# minted package - keyval error: breaklines undefined

Tags: minted

On Fedora 22 system: I installed `texlive-scheme-full`, Python 2.7 (and pygments 2.0.2) as well as all the pre-requisites for minted. I am trying to use the breaklines command with the minted package. I get a package keyval error: `breaklines undefined`. If I remove `breaklines` from the `\begin{minted}` line, the code compiles fine. As well, other parameters like `autogobble` also generate this error. I also cannot use the `\setminted` command. So, the minted package loads, but it seems kind of hamstrung. Here is the command that I run: `pdflatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "bash_functions".tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{upquote} 
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{minted}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\PYZsq{\textquotesingle}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}[linenos=true,breaklines]{bash}
{function h()
#
# Type 'h cmd' instead of 'cmd --help'
#
{
echo "--help" | xargs $1
}

\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Most probable your system is using an outdated version of the package (the automatic line breaking was recently introduced). Try updating.

Comment: I initially thought that having the most recent Pygment package, version 2.0.2, was all that I needed. I checked the time-stamp on the minted.sty file with the command: 'ls -la $(kpsewhich minted.sty)' and it said Sept. 18, 2011. So, I figured that was version 1.7. I then went to: https://github.com/gpoore/minted and cloned this repository to get version 2.1 which I copied to my Latex/Minted path: usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/minted and recompiled. It compiled correctly and I now have beautifully formatted code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was solved by updating `minted` package.